# Mypy shows error when using a function to return a type

Tags: python, mypy, typer

I have written a function `string_prompt` to return a type annotation which I have to reuse a lot in the context of [typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/). This is a working example (run with `python -m`):

```py
from typing import Annotated

import typer

app = typer.Typer()


def string_prompt(prompt: bool | str = True):
    return Annotated[str, typer.Option(prompt=prompt)]


@app.command()
def public(name: string_prompt(), project_number: string_prompt()):
    print(f"You called public with {name}, {project_number}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

This code works, but mypy shows the error:

> Invalid type comment or annotation ([valid-type](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_refs.html#code-valid-type)).
> Suggestion: use string_prompt[...] instead of string_prompt(...)

I've tried using square brackets instead, which obviously returns a syntax error, since I can't use square brackets to call a function.

Now my question is: Is there a different way I should declare this function to make mypy understand what I am trying to achieve? I had a look at the documentation of the mypy error, in which it explains, that functions are not a valid type, but the solution proposed which uses `Callable` is not applicable in my case, since I want to actually use the return value of the function called.

Comment: Yes that isn't a valid annotation. You cannot use a function call as an annotation.

Comment: `Annotated[str, typer.Option(prompt=True)]` is what you should use as your annotation.

Comment: well it works though, and since those annotations can get really long in typer I'd prefer to use a way to dynamically create the type hints...

Comment: It *doesn't* work though. Not as a type annotation in the Python type system. Which is presumably what you are asking about. You cannot dynamically create static type annotations. You want mypy to run your function, but mypy doesn't execute any code, it's a static analysis tool

Comment: ah okay, I see what you mean, e.g. `name` has no type in my example. This is somehow unfortunate, since typer heavily relies on those annotations for its functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not *exactly* what you wanted, but you can avoid type annotations getting overly long with type aliases.

For Python <= 3.11:

```
from typing import TypeAlias

string_prompt: TypeAlias = Annotated[str, typer.Option(prompt=True)]

@app.command()
def public(name: string_prompt, project_number: string_prompt) -> None:
    print(f"You called public with {name}, {project_number}")
```

For Python 3.12+:

```
type string_prompt = Annotated[str, typer.Option(prompt=True)]

@app.command()
def public(name: string_prompt, project_number: string_prompt) -> None:
    print(f"You called public with {name}, {project_number}")
```

The main limitation here is that you cannot pass arguments to `string_prompt` and thus cannot use another value for `prompt`. You could do that with "arguments" that are types, for example:

```
# Python <= 3.11
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')
prompt: TypeAlias = Annotated[T, typer.Option(prompt=True)]

# Python 3.12+
type prompt[T] = Annotated[T, typer.Option(prompt=True)]
```

... but the second argument to `Annotated` is a runtime value, ignored by type checkers and thus can't be parameterised by type checkers.

Comment: I haven't tested this, so I don't know if typer is compatible with generic type aliases or with the new syntax, but this should at least work from the mypy side of things!

Comment: It's definitely compatible, from typer's perspective, there is no difference

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I might use this, if it turns out that I am using `True` most of the time anyhow. I am thinking about using click instead of typer though now, since it seems that using your types for all the configuration leads to some hassle.

Comment: You're missing `Annotated` import - it's usually ok for answers, but you have other `typing` import, consider adding it explicitly there.

Comment: @STerliakov I didn't add anything to my answer that was already in the question and that I didn't change, including importing `Annotated` and `typer`, initialising `app` and the if-`__main__` section. It's what I usually do for clarity. Do you think it would be clearer if my answers were more self-contained?

Comment: @Jasmijn It's just my personal preference probably, but in type checking questions my favourite style is adding a playground link with external packages mocked if possible (e.g. often pydantic -> dataclasses), then only new parts in body to focus on important points. Copying all the initial code can be even harmful, of course. Playground link [like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict%2Cstrict-equality%2Cwarn-unreachable&gist=89c154236d17a23faa91d411b3525a81) allows to easily see `mypy` in action with the suggested solution, or full code that can be pasted there.